# SWIG - Java Proxy Class Array Parameter

Tags: java, c++, swig

I thought that this would be a simple problem but I have had some difficulty finding an answer.

I have a struct defined in C++, let's say:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

This gets wrapped into Java proxy class `MyStruct` by SWIG.  I have a function in C++ which takes an array of `struct MyStruct`s:

```
void myFunction(struct MyStruct arg[], int amount);
```

SWIG sees a pointer parameter and therefore generates the Java wrapper of the function to use a single `MyStruct` object as its parameter:

```
void myFunction(MyStruct arg, int amount) { /**/ }
```

How do I get SWIG to generate the Java function to take an array of `MyStruct` Java objects?  I have been able to figure it out for arrays of primitive types but have not found a way to get it working for custom wrapped types.

So my desired Java function signature would be this:

```
void myFunction(MyStruct[] arg, int amount);
```

**Edit**: Updated wording to use proper SWIG nomenclature of proxy classes.

Comment: Is this actually a variadic function?

Comment: @Flexo No, sorry I didn't think about how my syntax could be confused for that :P I edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: How does your C++ know the length of the array then? Is it fixed? Or magic end values? Or one of the omitted arguments? (What I'm getting at is that a real, working but minimal example makes it way easier to understand exactly what's needed)

Comment: @Flexo I have edited my question filling in the actual missing parameters of my function as well as added what I would like the generated Java function signature to be.

Comment: Assuming amount is auto populated by the length of the Java array passed in I'll try and write something up over the weekend if nobody beats me to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a working solution using an intermediary array class generated using `%array_class` from carrays.i along with `in` and `javain` typemaps.  A complete working example with the solution can be found in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbogochow/ff8568d2392537c4b766b3dcaf7dd836).

If anyone can come up with a better solution or improvements then I would be much appreciated.  A drawback of my solution is that you would need to create an additional Java array proxy class for each different proxy class that you wanted to use in this way, which could clutter up the Java API.  This could be improved slightly by making the array proxy classes package-private using the `javaclassmodifiers` typemap.